# How do I define a pairing $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ on $\textbf{R}^{3}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

Define a pairing $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$, based on the given matrix $A$, on $\textbf{R}^{3}\times\textbf{R}^{3}$ by $\langle v,w\rangle = v^{T}Aw$, where
\begin{align*}
A =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 4\\
3 & 0 & 5\\
4 & 5 & 6
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

Does this just mean I have to pick two random numbers to complete the dot product?

Answer (score 0):

This is defining an inner product of two vectors, chosen freely from $\Bbb R^3$, and the definition simply includes a fixed matrix $A$. You could think of it like a function of vectors in a sense:

$$f( \vec x,\vec y ) = \langle \vec x , \vec y \rangle = \vec x^T A \vec y$$

You don't "pick random numbers," but rather this definition applies for any vectors $\vec x, \vec y$ in $\Bbb R^3$. Moreover, you're not using a dot product; here, typical matrix multiplication is going on.